# Rendering a Grid/Sudoku Board in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm learning React native and trying to write a Sudoku app, but I'm really having trouble displaying a grid/sudoku board.

I've tried several ways, each of which results in an error. I'm a Python/C programmer and I'm used to rendering/displaying things the python way. I'm not really sure how to proceed.

I've also tried styling things using CSS, but since this is a sudoku board, I want to keep/store the whole board in one place

Any and all help is appreciated.

```
export default function App() {

  const [tileValue, setTileValue] = useState(0);

  const tileHandler = (enteredValue) => {
      setTileValue(enteredValue);
      console.log({enteredValue});
  };

  const [sudokuBoard, setSudokuBoard] = useState([]);

  let arr = [];

  for(let i = 0; i<9; i++) {
    arr[i] = []
  }

  for(let i = 0; i<9; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j<9; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = {value: {y: i, x: j}}
    }
  }
  console.log(arr)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={9}
        data={arr}
        renderItem={( itemData ) => (
          <View>
            {itemData.map((item) => <Text>{item}</Text>)}
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the state 9X9

```
 const [state, setState] = useState<BoardState>([
        null,null,null,.....................,null
        null,null,null,.....................,null
        .
        .
        null,null,null,.....................,null
        
    ])
```

Creating a state this way will help you debug your code. Imagine you need to try certain inputs, you can just manually add them.

Then you should map through this state. since you are going to interact with the screen, I think it is better to use Touchable opacity:

```
{state.map((cell, index) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                       // in certain situations disable it
                        disabled={disabled}
                       // you handle pressing
                        onPress={() => onCellPressed && onCellPressed(index)}
                        style={{
                            width: "11.1111%",
                            height: "11.1111%",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            alignItems: "center",
                            justifyContent: "center"
                        }}
                        key={index}
                    >
                        
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            })}
```